# Confusion on Connection Strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am deploying my app to two different places on my production server.  One is production, the other is for demo. There is a different database connection string for each.

My three connection strings are defined in `appsettings.json`. I have one for production, one for demo, and one for local testing. I have been changing the `builder.configuration.getConnectionString('xxx')` line in my `program.cs` file to change it to the desired database.

When I publish, there seems to be a way to select the connection string but I can't get it to work. I click on Publish, Show All Settings, Databases, and it gives me a list of my connection strings. I select the checkbox for the connection string I want and deploy. It doesn't override the setting in my `program.cs` file mentioned above.

While reviewing articles about this, I get more confused. It seems that config strings are stored in multiple places (`appsettings.json`, `web.config`, and user secrets file). I don't have any connection info in my `web.config` file. I just want to be able select the config string in my publish profile. The only way I can get this to work is to change the database in `program.cs`, recompile, and deploy.

What am I missing?

I can't find documentation on the portion of publish, where you select database connection strings. I have searched.

I am using VS 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally do this using "environments", with environment-specific configuration files.

So you'll have **one** connection string name:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=X;Database=Y;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=true"
  }
}
```

And that connection string configuration lives in your `appsettings.Development.json`. Then you'll have an `appsettings.Production.json` with its own connections string, still under "DefaultConnection" (or whatever you want to name it). Same goes for `appsettings.Production-Demo.json`

Then in your `.csproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will be included in your web.config as environment variable for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`, which determines which environment-specific configuration override (in addition to the base `appsettings.json`) will be loaded.

You can override this environment name during publish, by setting `/p:EnvironmentName=Production` *or* `/p:EnvironmentName=Production-Demo`.

Or you modify the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value in the web.config somehow during the actual web server deployment, for example using PowerShell.

See:

- MSDN/MS Docs/MS Learn: [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)
- MSDN/MS Docs/MS Learn: [Visual Studio publish profiles (.pubxml) for ASP.NET Core app deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles)

Comment: Thanks for info, but this doesn't explain what the point is for the database connect strings that show up under publish, show all settings, database....  It appears that this facility attempts to handle this a different way.

Comment: If you choose a connection string, this will be saved in the `.pubxml.user` file and be overwritten in your (environment-specific, if configured) appsettings file.

Comment: So I should make a appsettings.demo.json, appsettings.production.json, and appsettings.development.json file with proper connect strings.  Then publish will overwrite that connect string?  This seems really complicated to do something simple.  I just want to select a connection string that is not visible in the web.config.

Comment: I would not have my `dotnet publish` decide which environment the binaries and configuration are going to run in. It's up to the environment string and the accompanying configuration file that decide this.

Comment: I was able to get working by adding the appsettings.development.json, appsetting.Demo.jason, and appsetting.Production,json files, and then putting environment variable in web.config to identify which database to hit.